# No multipartconfig for servlet error from Jetty using scalatra

Tags: unit-testing, rest, embedded-jetty, scala-2.10, scalatra

I am trying to unit test an upload call but I get this error for the following code:

```
@MultipartConfig(maxFileSize = 3145728)
class WebServlet extends ScalatraServlet with FileUploadSupport {
  override def isSizeConstraintException(e: Exception) = e match {
    case se: ServletException if se.getMessage.contains("exceeds max filesize") ||
      se.getMessage.startsWith("Request exceeds maxRequestSize") => true
    case _ => false
  }
  error {
    case e: SizeConstraintExceededException => RequestEntityTooLarge("too much!")
  }
  post("/uploadscript") {
    val privateParam = try {params("private") != null && params("private").equals("true") } catch { case _ => false }
    println("privateParam = " + privateParam)
    val file = fileParams("file")
    println(s"The size of the file is ${file.size}")
  }
```

The error is:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No multipart config for servlet
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getParts(Request.java:2064) ~[jetty-server-8.1.10.v20130312.jar:8.1.10.v20130312]
    at org.scalatra.servlet.FileUploadSupport$class.getParts(FileUploadSupport.scala:133) ~[scalatra_2.10-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at org.scalatra.servlet.FileUploadSupport$class.extractMultipartParams(FileUploadSupport.scala:108) ~[scalatra_2.10-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at org.scalatra.servlet.FileUploadSupport$class.handle(FileUploadSupport.scala:79) ~[scalatra_2.10-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
    at com.ui.WebServlet.handle(WebServlet.scala:32) ~[classes/:na]
```

And this is my unit test, and the first one succeeds, so it is finding my webservice:

```
class WebServletSpecification extends MutableScalatraSpec {
  addServlet(classOf[WebServlet], "/*")

  "GET /hello" should {
    "return status 200" in {
      get("/hello/testcomputer") {
        status must_== 200
      }
    }
  }
  "POST /uploadscript" should {
    "return status 200" in {
    val scriptfile = "testfile"
    val scriptname = "basescript"
      post("/uploadscript", Map("private" -> "true"), Map("file" -> new File(scriptfile))) {
        status must_== 200
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am running this inside of Eclipse and I am not certain what is going on.

It works fine with using `HttpPost` and `MultipartEntity` so it seems to be a problem with Eclipse or how the scalatra specification framework works.

Any idea what may be going wrong?

I don't have a separate web.xml.

I am only using jetty 8.1.10, as seen from what I use in build.sbt:

> "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-webapp" % "8.1.10.v20130312" %
>   "container"

,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the solution I found when using ServletContextHandler and not WebAppContext. From here : https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=395000

```java
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder;
import javax.servlet.MultipartConfigElement;

public class WebServer {

    protected Server server;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int port = 8080;
        Server server = new Server(port);

        ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
        context.setContextPath("/");


        ServletHolder fileUploadServletHolder = new ServletHolder(new FileUploadServlet());
        fileUploadServletHolder.getRegistration().setMultipartConfig(new MultipartConfigElement("data/tmp"));
        context.addServlet(fileUploadServletHolder, "/fileUpload");

        server.setHandler(context);
        server.start();
        server.join();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

In case anyone else is looking for this in Jetty 9:

Add this to the request.handle( ... )

```
MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement = new MultipartConfigElement((String)null);
request.setAttribute(Request.__MULTIPART_CONFIG_ELEMENT, multipartConfigElement);
```

Comment: this does not even compile for me, __MULTIPART_CONFIG_ELEMENT is unknown field

Comment: I just checked (I hate outdated stuff on the interwebs too :) ) I have this as my jetty version: ```<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
    <version>9.3.8.v20160314</version>
   </dependency>```

Comment: For compilation, Request is org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request in 9.2 (for me this didn't fix the problem, now I am getting java.io.IOException: Incomplete parts)

Comment: thanks, this works like a charm after a jetty upgrade from 8.4 to 9.2.

Answer (score 2):

The `@MultipartConfig` is a Servlet spec 3.0 annotation.
You'll need to add the appropriate artifacts and configuration to support annotation in your Jetty environment.

You'll want the `jetty-annotations` and `jetty-plus` artifacts.

Then you'll want to setup the test server with the appropriate configurations.

like this...

*(I don't know the Scala specifics here, sorry)*

```java
package com.company.foo;

import org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration;
import org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.EnvConfiguration;
import org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.PlusConfiguration;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.Configuration;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.FragmentConfiguration;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaInfConfiguration;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.TagLibConfiguration;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration;

public class EmbedMe {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int port = 8080;
        Server server = new Server(port);

        String wardir = "target/sample-webapp-1-SNAPSHOT";

        WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();
        context.setResourceBase(wardir);
        context.setDescriptor(wardir + "WEB-INF/web.xml");
        context.setConfigurations(new Configuration[] {
                new AnnotationConfiguration(), new WebXmlConfiguration(),
                new WebInfConfiguration(), new TagLibConfiguration(),
                new PlusConfiguration(), new MetaInfConfiguration(),
                new FragmentConfiguration(), new EnvConfiguration() });

        context.setContextPath("/");
        context.setParentLoaderPriority(true);
        server.setHandler(context);
        server.start();
        server.join();
    }
}
```

This is from the https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-servlet-3.0 example project.

Comment: Thank you.  As I mentioned, when I start it from sbt (simple build tool) it works fine, as I can tell when I use a junit test that goes to the webserver.  But, when I try to use specs2, and I assume it is due to running in Eclipse, it isn't.  I don't want to make changes to the program for this unit test as much as understand why it isn't working.